# I'm trying to sort an array and then map it to a new array, but the sorting doesn't work (the map works)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting an array and then mapping it (as part of a to do list, I'm trying to sort the tasks in the global state before mapping it to a new array.

My sandbox is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/to-do-list-lloydr-416wm?file=/src/App.js

The place where I'm trying to do the sorting is here (I'm taking the global state of tasks as a prop and then sorting and mapping it to a new array - but only the mapping works, not the sorting):

```
const Tasks = ({ tasks, onDelete, onToggle }) => {

  return (
    <>
      {tasks
        .sort((a, b) =>
          new Date(a.selectedDate).getTime() >
          new Date(b.selectedDate).getTime()
            ? 1
            : -1
        )
        .map((task) => (
          <Task
            key={task.id}
            task={task}
            onDelete={onDelete}
            onToggle={onToggle}
          />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

The initial array of tasks is here:

```
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Doctor's appointment",
      selectedDate: "05/12/2021",
      // CHANGED DATE TO SELECTEDDATE
      priority: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Meet Lauren for Birthday Dinner",
      selectedDate: "27/09/2021",
      priority: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Take Nugie to vet cos she's stupid",
      selectedDate: "28/09/2021",
      priority: true
    }
  ]);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format it expects is `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Switch your month and day, or initialize it as a date instead of a string with `new Date(2021, 29, 27)` (for example).

Edit: I would recommend you to initialize dates with numbers instead of a string. This way you avoid thinking about which locale your string date should be introduced with

Comment: Thank you! that solved it :) Really apprecaite it.